# Multiple retrieve-marker inside fo:static-content

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop, static-content

In one of the sample code I am seeing:

```
<fo:static-content flow-name="rest-page-footer" font-family="Arial" font-style="normal" font-size="4">
    <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="lastPage" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="page"/>
    <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="continuedLine" retrieve-position="first-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="document"/>
    <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="continued" retrieve-position="last-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="page"/>
</fo:static-content>
```

So what will be the use case here; as it seems to me it is referring to 3 fo:maker s which can be followed by, please correct me if my understanding is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

Assuming there are `fo:marker` with corresponding `marker-class-name` values on FOs that generate their first areas on the current page, on the current page or any previous page, and on the current page, then the content of the `fo:static-content` will be from the content of those `fo:marker`.

Comment: <fo:marker marker-class-name="continuedLine">
fo:block>
<fo:leader leader-pattern="rule" leader-pattern-width="0.5pt" leader-length="175mm" color="cmyk(0,0,0,0.3)"/>
</fo:block>
</fo:marker>
So in case if this is continuedLine maker class then what should be the out come for
<fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="continuedLine" retrieve-position="first-starting-within-page" retrieve-boundary="document"/>
this retrival?
More importanly how I cam visualized and validate the impact of retrieve-position retrieve-boundary

Comment: What I am not able to understand is 1. After marker retrieval; how i can identify the produced area (available dimension [height; length may be] for my element to represent)? 2. Impact that i can visualized for different retrieve-position retrieve-boundary?

Comment: The retrieved marker becomes part of the content of the `fo:static-content`. The space available for the `fo:static-content` and the rest of the content of the `fo:static-content` determines how much space the retrieved marker takes up/has available. For example, if the `fo:retrieve-marker` is in an `fo:table-cell` within the `fo:static-content`, then obviously the space available for the marker content is constrained by the table layout and the width of the current table column.